# Tableau - Comparing one against an average of many on same worksheet

Tags: tableau-api

I'm looking to compare a single Fortune 500 company's revenues (selected by the end user from a list of all Fortune 500 companies) to an average revenue for all Fortune 500 companies over time. I would like the averages to show up as bars and the single company revenues to show as a line graph (both on the same chart).

I understand how to set two different chart types on the same view. What I don't understand is how to write the calculations and parameters to give the end user the functionality of choosing a single company and comparing it against all others.

Any suggestions on how to do this? Happy to clarify further if needed.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Tableau right now to test, but I believe that kind of chart can be achieved using 2 measures.

Well, you need to create the measures then. The average of all is pretty straight forward, it's AVG(Revenue).

The single company revenue can be retrieved using parameters. Create a parameter like [Company chosen], and put the list of all Fortune 500 (you can load from field, which helps a lot).

Then create a calculated field [Company revenue]:

```
IF [Company] = [Company chosen]
THEN [Revenue]
END
```

And just use the sum or avg of this measure.

Put both the measures on the worksheet and set the right chart

Answer (score 1):

I am using the superstore data that ships with Tableau.

You can create an LOD calculation to calculate the average:

```
SUM({FIXED [Order Date (Months)] : SUM([Sales])}) / SUM( {COUNTD([Sub-Category])})
```

This is calculating the total sales at each month and summing the sales and then dividing that by the number of points for each month (thereby giving you an average of sales per month).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

FYI, I submitted this question to Tableau. They replied with a workbook using the Superstore data with the following instructions:

1. Add Year(Order Date) to the column.
2. Add Sales to the row.
3. Create a parameter called Select Country with the following settings:

   - Name: Select Country
   - Data Type: String
   - Allowable Values: List
   - Add from field: Country/Region
   - Select OK.
4. After creating the parameter, Right Click on the parameter in the data pane and select Show Parameter Control.
5. Create a calculated field Country Sale called with the following formula:

   - IF [Country / Region] = [Select Country] THEN [Sales] END
6. Add Country Sale to the Rows Shelf.
7. Go to Sum(Country Sale) tab on the Marks Pane and select Line from the drop down.
8. Right Click on the Country Sales axis and select Dual Axis.
9. Right Click on the Country Sales axis and select Synchronize Axis.